# How do I rename c# types in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, types

I need to redeclare a type called "Matrix4" to "Matrix" so that all references to "Matrix" will redirect to "Matrix4". Is there any simple way to do this without doing something drastic like a wrapper?

The reason I need this is for conditional library inclusions.

```
    #if USE_XNA
        using Library = XNA;
    #elif USE_OPENTK
        using OpenTK;
    #endif
    #if USE_OPENTK
        //Set "Matrix4" references to "Matrix"
    #endif
```

Matrix4 in OpenTK is roughly the same type as the Matrix type in XNA except it has a different identifier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either you rename Matrix4 to Matrix like Random832 said or you declare an alias:

```
using Matrix = Namespace.Matrix4;
```

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the name, select "Refactor -> Rename...".

That'll handle everything within the solution. If this is a public class in a library, you may need to change anything else that uses it too.

Comment: I can't do that; I have conditional preprocessors that change library references.

Comment: Maybe define your own matrix type that can just be freely converted (with implicit conversion operators) to and from whatever the library's matrix type is. (Please add the details about the two classes coming from two different libraries you are conditionally using to the question).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call a wrapper class "drastic," I'd call it the correct solution.

If *anything* else differs between the interfaces of those two libraries - method names, method parameter types, even the order of parameters - you are pretty much boned.

You should wrap `Matrix/Matrix4` into a wrapper interface, and use that interface throughout the program... and do the same for any other classes you need from the two libraries.